# Remote debugging for Flash CS6 and AIR iOS?

Tags: ios, debugging, air, flash-cs6

I'm using Flash CS6 and I would like to debug an AIR iOS app on my device but I can't establish a connection. I have my iPod Touch 5G connected via USB, checked "allow remote debugging", published the .ipa for "device debugging" and started the AS3 debugging session from the debug panel.

All I get is a window on my iPod that says enter HOST or IP. I tried both but the window comes up every time again and again without connecting. What step do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your computer and iPod are connected to the same wifi network.

Comment: I double checked - they are connected to the same wifi network. Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

Delete the app from your device and watch it as your app is installed to make sure that Flash is actually installing a new binary. (mine sometimes doesn't).

Try unplugging your phone, refresh device list, then re-plugging it in and refreshing the device list before starting the debug.

Try doing Debug menu > Debug Movie > On Device via USB > select your device. (to do this the .fla file must be the active file within Flash.) Note I'm using Flash Pro CC 2014 though, not CS6.

Comment: Thanks but I need to get it to work for Flash CS 6, there is no device list.